# rails route set a new path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Im new to rails, Im trying to route
`0.0.0.0:3000/ratings/list`
to the controller `ratings` and the method `list`

but instead I get directed the `index` method with `list` as the parameter

my routes.rb is like so

```
resources :ratings
  match 'ratings/:won/update/:lost' => 'ratings#update'
  match 'ratings/list' => 'ratings#list'
```

and rake routes is

```
ratings      GET    /ratings(.:format)                   ratings#index
             POST   /ratings(.:format)                   ratings#create
  new_rating GET    /ratings/new(.:format)               ratings#new
 edit_rating GET    /ratings/:id/edit(.:format)          ratings#edit
      rating GET    /ratings/:id(.:format)               ratings#show
             PUT    /ratings/:id(.:format)               ratings#update
             DELETE /ratings/:id(.:format)               ratings#destroy
                    /ratings/:won/update/:lost(.:format) ratings#update
ratings_list        /ratings/list(.:format)              ratings#list
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to use collection route

```
resources :ratings do
  collection do
    get 'list'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
match 'ratings/list' => 'ratings#list'
```

before

```
resources :ratings
```

Rails routes are first come, first served!

Comment: on the same subject Im trying to delete a specific row by `<a href="/ratings.9" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>` And i get an exception `No route matches [DELETE] "/ratings.8"`